# Is it ok to stack search results that way?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a search feature in my react-native that is like the youtube one ( the search results get stacked and each time the user press the go back button he gets the previous result). I was thinking of doing so by creating a stack and each time the user make a search I push the previous result to the stack and show the new search result but I am worried if this would affect the app performance. Can any one approve my approach if no how can I reach the wished result ?

Comment: You won't have any problems with performance, if you use `Redux`.